# How can I disable one switch in a three-way circuit?

Tags: wiring

I replaced a ceiling fan with a regular light a while back that originally had 2 switches that worked it. When I was done only one switch worked. I was okay with this because I didn't use the other switch anyway. Well yesterday I removed the switch (the non used one) to put a blank plate on the wall. (To get rid of the switched that were of no use). So I capped off all wires from the switch, but now I can't use the original switch I'd been using. (It makes sense that I cause disruption in the way things connected it just didn't occur to me that it would happen). What can I do to make connection behind this plate without putting a switch back in, if anything?

The red and the black at the bottom are the hot, nothing on the others. There are three sets of wires, any help would be appreciative. They can be labeled as A B and C.

[image]I replaced a ceiling fan with a regular light a while back that originally had 2 switches that worked it. When I was done only one switch worked, I was okay with this because I didn't use the other switch anyway. Well yesterday I removed the switch (the non used one) to put a blank plate on the wall. (To get rid of the switched that were of no use). So I capped off all wires from the switch, but now I can't use the original switch I'd been using. (It makes sense that I cause disruption in the way things connected it just didn't occur to me that it would happen). What can I do to make connection behind this plate without putting a switch back in, if anything?

The red and the black at the bottom are the hot, nothing on the others. There are three sets of wires, any help would be appreciative. They can be labeled as A B and C.

Comment: This is not a general question.  This is particular to the wiring of that circuit.  With good photos or a wiring diagram an absolute answer is possible.  Without it, no answer is possible other than, "Undo whatever you did that broke the circuit."

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. You should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Can you post photos of the wiring involved?

Comment: @feetwet My answer may or may not be complete/best, but there are definitely answers possible here. Would it be better if the switch removal could simply be "undone"? Yes. But that might actually be harder than simply figuring out the remaining wires and the other switch.

Answer (score 1):

To know for sure, we need to see pictures of the wiring and switches. But I'll make an educated guess:

#### Common (Shared) Hot

The two switches shared a common hot wire. One hot in, two switched hots out. There are three ways to connect one hot to two switches:

- Two switches built together with a common hot
  This is the easy way - essentially two switches in the space of one. I know you didn't have this, because if you did then there would be no way to remove one switch without removing the other switch. But listing it for completeness.
- Pigtail Hots
  This is the preferred method because it avoids the problem you found. The hot wire comes in to the box and is connected to two short wires, *pigtails*. Each pigtail connects to one of the switches.
- Daisy Chain Hots
  Hot wire comes in and connects to switch # 1. Another wire connects from switch # 1 to switch # 2. The two connections on switch # 1 could be two wires under one screw (not usually recommended, but often done anyway) or one wire under a screw and one wire in a backstab connection. If you disconnect all wires from switch # 1, then there is no longer any hot wire for switch # 2.

You need to look at the wires going to the remaining switch. You should have one wire going out of the box to the light and one wire going out of the box back towards the circuit breaker. What I suspect you will find is that one of the wires actually has the other end loose, but capped, in the box. That is your formerly-hot wire. The hard part is figuring out which wire from the removed switch is the hot wire. The easiest way to figure this out is a [non-contact voltage tester](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Klein-Tools-Non-Contact-Voltage-Tester-NCVT-1SEN/100661787):
[image]

With the breaker **on**, use the tester to identify the hot wire. Turn the breaker off and then connect that wire to the switch instead of the loose/capped wire.

Comment: I will need to get the voltage tester tool. In the meantime, I am just wanting to make the connection without having switches. I wanted to put a plain face plate over the wiring. I don't need to have switches because they didn't work anyway, but they must have made some sort of electrical connection.

Comment: Most likely the original configuration was to have one switch for the fan itself and one switch for an attached light. Many fans don't have lights, and many newer fans that have lights control everything with a remote control so that the switch (just one switch) turns power to everything on/off but isn't even needed since you can do everything with the remote.

Comment: Is there a way to make the wires connect for the power without using a switch. Where I can just have it capped off or something behind the solid switch plate?

Comment: Yes. If you figure out which wires *should* be on the switch and then just wire nut them together, you can then take out the switch. But then the light will be always on. Is that what you want?

Comment: I am just now getting back to my issue, back to school is always a crazy time. Anyway, I do not want my light to stay on. I took a picture, but it makes no sense to me.... how do I get the picture up here?

Comment: @Diana Click "Edit" below the question and one of the icons above the text box should be a box with "mountains" for uploading pictures. If you can't get that to work, just upload the picture to imgur.com and put the link in the question and someone will turn it into an embedded picture.

Comment: thank you. I added the photo. And unfortunately of course I do not know what wiring I took what switches off. I'm an idiot, I know :-)  I know better, I should always pay attention to how I take things apart. But I didn't think it would cause the disruption. I have tried multiple things with new switches I bought just to see if I could get my kitchen light come on again.  Any help you can provide is appreciated.

Comment: "that originally had 2 switches that worked it" do you mean two switches right next to each other with one switch operating the fan and the other switch operating the light. Or do you mean one switch on one wall and the other switch on another wall.

Comment: One switch on one wall and the other switch on the other wall.

Comment: It seems like I'm going to have to call an electrician, I just can't afford one. I tried to do the more simple jobs myself, but this turned out to be a "not"  simple job.  Only because of my stupidity in the beginning.

Comment: I certainly understand "can't afford one". But there are times when that is really the only option - I do a lot of my own electrical but sometimes it is too much for me to attempt myself. Same with water. And **always** when it comes to gas. Everyone has to know their limits.

Comment: You are right, I just can't believe I brought this on myself by my own stupidity! I think my son-in-law has a friend that is an electrician so I might get a "friends & family" discount...... (fingers crossed)